# Is there a benefit to using multiple buckets on Amazon S3 versus consolidating into a single bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

We currently serve up downloadable content (mp3, pdf, mp4, zip files, etc) in a single S3 bucket called *media.domainname.com*.

We have a separate bucket that stores all the various video encodings for our iOS app: *app.domainname.com*.

We're investigating moving all of our images to S3 as well in order to ease the server load and prep us for moving to a load balanced server setup.

That said, is it better/more efficient to move our images to a separate bucket i.e., *images.domainname.com*? Or is it a better practice to create an images subfolder in the media bucket, like *media.domainname.com/images*?

What are the pros/cons of either method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The primary benefits of using separate buckets are that you can assign separate policies to each:

- Reduced redundancy to save on costs.
- Versioning of changed contents.
- Automatic archival to Glacier
- Separate permissions

The only downside that I can think of is that it means you'd have to manage all these things separately across multiple buckets.

Comment: This definitely makes it more clear for me. I think the benefits far outweigh the downside of managing multiple buckets. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "reduced redundancy"?

Comment: I believe "reduced redundancy" here refers to S3's Reduced Redundancy Storage -- more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html